# Jenkins Pipeline: SCP commnd not working when executed through pipeline, same works fine through GIT Bash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, scp

I have two ubuntu aws instance and below are following details

1. DevServer: 172.31.29.201
2. QAServer: 172.31.30.52

I establish a passwordless SSH between two machine bu generating ssh-keygen in DevServer and copied it to QAServer using ssh-copy-id ubuntu@172.31.30.52 [ubuntu is username and 172.31.30.52 is private ip address of the QAServer)

I'm able to successfully make a SSH connection to the QAServer from DevServer without any issue

[image]

Even scp command to transfer the .war file to the QAServer tomcat8/webapps is successful. File qaapp.war is transferred to the tomcat8/webapps/ folder

```
ubuntu@DevServer:~$ scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline_dev_01/webapp/target/webapp.war ubuntu@172.31.30.52:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war
webapp.war

100% 3125     3.8MB/s   00:00

ubuntu@DevServer:~$
```

Pipeline code:

```
node('built-in') 
{
    stage('ContinousDownload') 
    {
        git 'https://github.com/rasivana/maven.git'
    }
    stage('ContinousBuild') 
    {
        sh 'mvn package'
    }
    stage('ContinousDeployment')
    {
        sh 'scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline_dev_01/webapp/target/webapp.war ubuntu@172.31.30.52:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war'
    }
}
```

We get following error

[image]

Complete logs:

```
+ scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline_dev_01/webapp/target/webapp.war ubuntu@172.31.30.52:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 172.31.30.52, user ubuntu, command scp -v -t /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.31.30.52 [172.31.30.52] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.31.30.52:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:428mcfQF4kAq6DMmrP68kF6nz18rUZlKA3DjtsTcrpk
debug1: Host '172.31.30.52' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
Load key "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@172.31.30.52: Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

Same with cmd prompt scp works file and file gets transferred. Thought first time it asked for ubuntu user passowrd. Pasting below for analysis

```
ubuntu@DevServer:~$ scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline_dev_01/webapp/target/webapp.war ubuntu@172.31.30.52:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 172.31.30.52, user ubuntu, command scp -v -t /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.31.30.52 [172.31.30.52] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.31.30.52:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:428mcfQF4kAq6DMmrP68kF6nz18rUZlKA3DjtsTcrpk
debug1: Host '172.31.30.52' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:UHBTYkIj/Zm87NrPLFNOwz8/1bzOtM9ahxtdwcCfKIA /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 172.31.30.52 ([172.31.30.52]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/qaapp.war
Sending file modes: C0644 3125 webapp.war
Sink: C0644 3125 webapp.war
webapp.war                                                                                                                                                 100% 3125     4.2MB/s   00:00
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 5972, received 2648 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12812.5, received 5681.1
debug1: Exit status 0
ubuntu@DevServer:~$
```

Why same command when executed through GIT Bash works without any error, and command executed through jenkins pipe line execution is not working?

Attaching a text comparison between the Jenkins execution and GIT bash execution image file.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post things like that into comments that are unreadable. Use [edit] link to add things to your question, and format them properly, for example with the code format tool.

Comment: @JamesZ, I have correct the content and added more information. Thanks

Comment: It should be obvious, that user `jenkins` has no SSH keys added...

Comment: Thanks @MartinZeitler, I created a SSH from Jenkins user and transferred the ssh to remote machine which already has password less SSH setup. Now i'm able to transfer the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When triggered through Jenkins, default user is 'jenkins' and not ubuntu when i tried manually. So I switched the user to 'jenkins', created a new SSH file using 'ssh-keygen'. Transferred the newly created SSH file to QA server.

Now executing the scp command uses the SSH file and able to transfer the file.

[image]

Comment: How can you do this part ? 

created a new SSH file using 'ssh-keygen'. Transferred the newly created SSH file to QA server.

I'm using the same  `scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no....` 

command but in my cpanel I can't generate new ssh key I think, there is no place for that, you can do it only manually.